# Multiple Jquery ajax form requests and seperate results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have several forms on my page, and I use this script for all of them basically to call an action:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {

        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#result').html(result.result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Each form has inside it a div which will contai the result. BUT on this step i have a question as i have single jquery script for all of them, how can i seperate the results, that they should be associated with the form (div which is inside current form)?

Comment: What do you mean by separating the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
       var thisform = $(this);
        if (currentform.valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    thisform.find('.result').html(result.result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Within your forms, use a class instead of an ID, as ID's are unique.

```
<form> ..<div class="result"></div> </form>
```

---

**So the key part here was the context of the form you are submitting**

```
current form > find > element
```

...

```
thisform.find('.result').html(result.result);
```

We also assigned the active form to a variable - no need to recreate the jquery object each time

```
var thisform = $(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current form context and find the div inside "this".

```
$.ajax({
  url: this.action,
  type: this.method,
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  context: this,
  success: function (result) {
        $(this).find('#result').html(result.result);
  }
});
```